# Firefox portable - Store cache on disk instead of RAM?

Tags: firefox, caching

I'd like to store Firefox Portable's Cache files **locally on disk** in the folder where I installed it (ie. C:\FirefoxPortable\Cache or wutever) rather than in RAM. Is this possible? I googled around and couldn't find a method. I checked the **about:config** but I dont want to touch anything that could make things worse. Anyone know? thanks